# How to center pictures in span?

Tags: html, css, image, resize-image

I want to center picutes in a span. The span has the class `centerMe` but it doesn't affect the pictures.

Markup of `centerMe`:

```
.region.region-footer .centerMe{
    text-align: center;
  }
```

You can find this example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vg4Y5/).

Thanks for any help

Comment: where is .region in that fiddle?

Comment: @user3168736 the .region.region-footer is from my drupal template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not happening because `span` is an inline element.

`text-align:center` does not affect it because total width of images and width of span is exactly same. If you give it 100% width, then only you will see the difference.

Also, `width` property will not work on `inline` element so change it to `block` or `inline-block`.

Add `width` to the markup:

```
.centerMe {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vg4Y5/2/) here.

Another solution is to use any `block` element like `div`,`p` or `section` rather than using `span`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `text-align:` that way on inline elements.

If you want to achieve that, you will have to change your span into i.e. a `<p>` element, which is a block.

Answer (score 0):

The span itself doesn't have full width, so there is no space to center the images in. 
You can solve this by changing the `span` into a `div`.

Or you can make it behave like a div by adding `display: block` to the CSS:

```
.centerMe{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Alternatively, you can give it `width: 100%`, like Hiral suggested but then you will have to take any borders, padding and margin into account as well. By making it behave like a block element, it will automatically occupy the available space, and I think it is a more flexible solution.